# Navigate to URL from another page in C# Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

In Windows Forms applications, we usually use the code below to navigate the appropriate URL:

`WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1 BrowserWindow = new Form1;`

`BrowserWindow.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.something.com/");`

What if I want to do this on a Windows Phone 8 C# Application? How is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use a Web Browser Task.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394020(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but that's not what I want... I want to navigate the URL from another page, then open that link to a different page that has webBrowser control inserted to it

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Phone 8 you can use the `WebBrowser` control as well. However, in stead of provinding a string, you need to provide an `Uri`.

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.something.com", UriKind.Absolute));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but that's not what I want... I want to navigate the URL from another page, then open that link to a different page that has webBrowser control inserted to it